# bash script to bulk resize using Imagemagick

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I need to convert a very large number of images JPEGs. those images some are 720px × 480px, and some 300x400 and some 2000x1400 and some are 1000x1000 etc..
    I only need to resize those images to 1000x1000 without touch the images that have 1000x1000

here i try to make small script which is calculate the total size of each image w x h but i need to add if statement on it which is convert all images to 1000x1000 and exclude images that have 1000x1000 size

```
for image in *.jpg; do
IFS=x 
read w h < <(identify "$image" | grep -oP '\d+x\d+(?=\+)')  
echo $((w*h)) "$image"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `fx` operator to filter images based on *height* & *width* e.g.

```
identify -format '%[fx:(h=1000 && w=1000)]\n' image.jpg
```

will output `1` if the image is exactly `1000x1000` and `0` otherwise.
So you could run something like this (adjust the `convert` command as per your needs):

```
for image in ./*.jpg; do
identify -format '%[fx:(h=1000 && w=1000)]\n' "$image" | grep -q 0 \
&& convert -resize 1000x1000 "$image" "${image%.*}"-converted.jpg
done
```